# libsuperuser get command output in real time

Tags: java, android, root

I've never used libsuperuser but only roottools. Now I want to switch to libsuperuser but I don't find a way to call a command as root and read its output without wait for comand finish.
With roottools it was easy because it has a method that's called each time a new line is written to stdout by the process.
But with libsuperuser I have only found `Shell.SU.run()` that returns the output but only when the process is finished. How can I read the output lines in realtime with libsuperuser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `Shell.Interactive.addCommand()` with its callback:

```
Shell.Interactive rootSession = new Shell.Builder().useSU().open(/*...*/);
```

Once the session is open, you can add commands:

```
rootSession.addCommand(new String[] { "ls -l /sdcard" },
    1, // a command id
    new Shell.OnCommandLineListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCommandResult(int commandCode, int exitCode) {
            // ...
        }
        @Override
        public void onLine(String line) {
            // ...
        }
    });
```

The `onLine(String line)` is what you are looking for.

See [sample code "InteractiveActivity"](https://github.com/Chainfire/libsuperuser/blob/master/libsuperuser_example/src/eu/chainfire/libsuperuser_example/InteractiveActivity.java) from Chainfire's libsuperuser repository.